# Question about when the implication is true and the converse is false.

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Suppose I have the implication $P \rightarrow \lnot Q$ that is known to be true. This means all truth values are valid for $P$ and $Q$ except for $P$ being true while $Q$ is true. Suppose it is also known that the converse $\lnot Q \rightarrow P$ is false, meaning that when $\lnot Q$ is true that $P$ is false. Taking the contrapositive of $\lnot Q \rightarrow P$ gives the inverse $\lnot P \rightarrow Q$, which must share the same truth value with the original converse. It is clear that when $P$ is true, $Q$ must be false. It is also shown that when $P$ is false, $Q$ must be false, showing $Q$ is never true. Looking at the truth tables, this seems to be correct. Is this a correct approach?

Answer (score 2):

Given that $\lnot Q \rightarrow P$ is false, I would not say "when $\lnot Q$ is true [then] $P$ is false". Instead I would simply say "$\lnot Q$ is true and $P$ is false". In particular, $\lnot Q$ is true, which means $Q$ is false. (Note that your argument seems to allow the possibility that $P$ is true, which is not the case here.)

The negation of an implication $A\rightarrow B$ is the conjunction $A\land\lnot B$. Your phrasing seems more like the (incorrect) negation $A\rightarrow\lnot B$.

If you are thinking of $P$ and $Q$ as open sentences involving some variable that has a quantifier attached to it, then I still don't think your interpretation is correct, because the type of quantifier (universal or existential) matters a lot.